# Hapi jwt extra auth check on owner id

Tags: hapi.js

I'm working on a project
using  hapi-auth-jwt.
So when the user is logged
get this token

```
exports.getUserToken = function getUserToken(user) {
    var userData = {
        username: user.username,
        scope: ['user'],
        iss: apiConfig.iis,
        jti: user.id
    };
    var token = {
        token : Jwt.sign(userData, apiConfig.secret, { expiresInMinutes: apiConfig.expiresInMinutes})
    };
    return token;
};
```

and in the route

```
{
            method: 'GET',
        path:  internals.resourcePath + '/{userId}',
        config : {
               handler : User.findById,
               validate: Validator.findById,
               auth: {
                    strategy: 'token',
                    scope: ['user']
                }
        }
        },
```

but I've to do an other check like
(in controller for get one ,update and delete )
to see if the user is really the owner

```
var jti = request.auth.credentials.jti;
var id = +request.params.userId;
if( id !== jti ){
    return reply( ReplyUtil.forbidden() );
}
var params =request.payload;
User.findOne
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to not to have
my code duplicated (sort of middleware in express)

Is it worth using a pre-hook like

```
server.ext('onPostAuth' , function(request, reply) {
   if(request.auth && request.auth.credentials &&    request.auth.credentials.jti){
        var jti = request.auth.credentials.jti;
        var id = +request.params.userId;
        if( id !== jti ){
            return reply(Boom.forbidden());
        }
    }
    return reply.continue();
});
```

Comment: You could use a shared route prerequisite http://hapijs.com/api#route-prerequisites to check ownership

Comment: @MattHarrison thanks for the point now I'm in two minds using onPostAuth or a pre flag. imo in this case onPostAuth seems clearer but ...

Comment: Personally, I'd go pre. It's not global logic and it's better documented in your route config for when you look at the code in a year and try to understand what's going on.

Comment: Another reason is that params won't have validated yet in your onPostAuth wheras they will in a pre: http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

First, in your validateFunc, add user's scope his/her id:

```
user.scope.push(user._id);
```

When you call callback function in validateFunc, don't forget to pass the user object as credentials. Then in your route, define scope something like this:

```
auth: {
  strategy: 'token',
  scope: ['admin', 'USER_ID']
}
```

Hope it helps.